# How can I remove duplicates from a vector of custom structs?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to remove duplicates in the below example:

```
struct User {
    reference: String,
    email: String,
}

fn main() {
    let mut users: Vec<User> = Vec::new();
    users.push(User {
        reference: "abc".into(),
        email: "test@test.com".into(),
    });
    users.push(User {
        reference: "def".into(),
        email: "test@test.com".into(),
    });
    users.push(User {
        reference: "ghi".into(),
        email: "test1@test.com".into(),
    });

    users.sort_by(|a, b| a.email.cmp(&b.email));
    users.dedup();
}
```

I'm getting the error

```
error[E0599]: no method named `dedup` found for type `std::vec::Vec<User>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:23:11
   |
23 |     users.dedup();
   |           ^^^^^
   |
```

How can I remove duplicates from `users` by `email` values? Can I implement the `dedup()` function for `struct User` or do I have to do something else?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [`Vec::dedup`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.dedup), you'll note that it's in a little section marked by the following:

```
impl<T> Vec<T>
where
    T: PartialEq<T>,
```

This means that the methods below it exist *only* when the given constraints are satisfied.  In this case, `dedup` isn't there because `User` doesn't implement the `PartialEq` trait. Newer compiler errors even state this explicitly:

```
   = note: the method `dedup` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `User : std::cmp::PartialEq`
```

In this particular case, you can derive `PartialEq`:

```
#[derive(PartialEq)]
struct User { /* ... */ }
```

It's generally a good idea to derive all applicable traits; it would probably be a good idea to *also* derive `Eq`, `Clone` and `Debug`.

> How can I remove duplicates from `users` by `email` values?

You can use [`Vec::dedup_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.dedup_by):

```
users.dedup_by(|a, b| a.email == b.email);
```

In other cases, you might be able to use [`Vec::dedup_by_key`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.dedup_by_key)