# Is there a simple way remove duplicate elements from an array?

Tags: arrays, rust, duplicates

I want to remove duplicate elements from an array:

```
use itertools::Itertools;
use std::collections::HashSet;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Person {
    name: String,
    age: u32,
}

fn main() {
    let arr = [
        Person { name: "aaa".to_string(), age: 10 },
        Person { name: "bbb".to_string(), age: 20 },
        Person { name: "bbb".to_string(), age: 20 },
        Person { name: "ccc".to_string(), age: 30 },
    ];

    // Way 1:
    let arr2 = {
        let names: Vec<_> = arr.iter().map(|v| v.name.clone()).unique().collect();
        names
            .iter()
            .map(|name| arr.iter().find(|person| &person.name == name).unwrap())
            .collect::<Vec<_>>()
    };
    dbg!(arr2);

    // Way 2:
    let arr2 = {
        let mut names = HashSet::new();
        arr.iter()
            .filter(|p| names.insert(p.name.clone()))
            .collect::<Vec<_>>()
    };
    dbg!(arr2);

    /*
    expect:
        [
            Person{name: "aaa".to_string(), age: 10},
            Person{name: "bbb".to_string(), age: 20},
            Person{name: "ccc".to_string(), age: 30},
        ]
    */
}
```

Way 2 is simple compared to way 1, but is there anything simpler?

Comment: Take a look at vec:dedup() If you just want to remove duplicated _contiguous_ elements. If you don't mind about the order, vec.sort_by(), then vec:dedup()

Comment: @Iñigo `dedup_by` or `dedup_by_key` would be more applicable as they want to dedup based on the name, not on the Person structure.

Comment: An other option would be to use a wrapper implementing Hash and Eq delegated to `name` (implementing such on Person directly seems like a terrible idea), then get the entire thing through `HashSet`, or `IndexMap::IndexSet` to keep the ordering, and optionally back to a vector.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's a difference between the `dedup` and `unique` method in [`Itertools`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.9.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.unique_by), where the former operates on contiguous elements, i.e:

```rust
[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1].iter().dedup()  // [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1].iter().unique() // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If you're looking to have unique elements by `name`, [`unique_by`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.9.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.unique_by) might do:

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Person {
    name: String,
    age: u32,
}

fn main() {
    let arr = [
        Person { name: "aaa".to_string(), age: 10 },
        Person { name: "bbb".to_string(), age: 20 },
        Person { name: "bbb".to_string(), age: 20 }, // Duplicate
        Person { name: "ccc".to_string(), age: 30 },
    ];

    let res = arr.iter().unique_by(|p| &p.name).collect::<Vec<_>>();
}
```

```
[
  Person { name: "aaa", age: 10 },
  Person { name: "bbb", age: 20 },
  Person { name: "ccc", age: 30 }
]
```

Comment: It should also be noted that `unique` and o.p.'s approach rely on cloning something, whereas `unique_by` can operate on references. I'm honestly not sure why unique relies on cloning the entire thing when it could just as easily rely on simply taking a reference.

Comment: rust cannot resolve itertools when i use it like you did. what might be the problem?

Comment: @Eren, [Itertools](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.0/itertools/) is a separate crate that expands the functionality offered for iterators. Did you add it as a dependency to your [`Cargo.toml`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/dependencies.html)?

Comment: @Jason I did but it was not working. This morning, I rerun it without making a change and it did. I guess I just needed to restart the workspace because something got stuck.

Comment: in 2022, `[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1].iter().unique()` returns `Unique { iter: UniqueBy { iter: Iter([1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]), used: {}` . How to fix this?

Comment: @DoneDeal0 If you actually use the returned iterator, it will automatically remove duplicates and return the unique elements only.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [`Itertools::unique`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.9.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.unique) and [`Itertools::unique_by`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.9.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.unique_by) help. They use a `Hash`-based approach.

Answer (score 2):

With nightly Rust, this can be done in-place and with no additional memory allocation via [`slice::partition_dedup_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.partition_dedup_by):

```rust
#![feature(slice_partition_dedup)]

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Person {
    name: String,
    age: u32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut arr = [
        Person { name: "aaa".to_string(), age: 10 },
        Person { name: "bbb".to_string(), age: 20 },
        Person { name: "bbb".to_string(), age: 20 },
        Person { name: "ccc".to_string(), age: 30 },
    ];

    arr.sort_by(|a, b| a.name.cmp(&b.name));
    let (unique, _) = arr.partition_dedup_by(|a, b| a.name == b.name);
    
    dbg!(unique);
}
```

This doesn't actually *remove* the duplicate elements, it just moves them to the end of the original slice / array / `Vec`. It's impossible to remove values from an array because an array has a fixed length.

See also:

- [How can I remove duplicates from a vector of custom structs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30977752/155423)
- [Vec::dedup does not work — how do I deduplicate a vector of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47636618/155423)

Comment: This method now throws the error: 
use of unstable library feature 'slice_partition_dedup' (solution.rs)
note: see issue #54279 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54279> for more information

Answer (score 2):

I would use a Hashmap to get an overview of existing values to retain. This is a slim approach that doesn't require external dependencies.

```rust
let mut arr = vec![1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5];
let mut seen: HashMap<i32, bool> = HashMap::new();

// Iterate over the array and mark values as "seen"
arr.retain(|&x| seen.insert(x, true).is_none());

println!("{:?}", arr); // -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=650cca88f76b3ae06726675355a810b3)

If your array consists of struct or enum values you'll need to add `derive(Hash)`.

It's actually this platform that taught me that approach quite a while ago when working with Lua tables. Unfortunately, I can't find the related article.

Comment: If you do not need to store any values, just use a HashSet instead.

Comment: And it gets much simpler with a HashSet: `vec.retain(|x| seen.insert(x))` 

Answer (score 2):

My solution consuming the vector

```rust
    let foo = vec![1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5];
    eprintln!(
        "{:?}",
        foo.into_iter()
            .collect::<std::collections::HashSet<u32>>()
            .into_iter()
            .collect::<Vec<u32>>()
    );
```

The problem is that the output is not ordered as it was before

Answer (score 1):

This method operates in place, visiting each element exactly once in the original order, and preserves the order of the retained elements.

This works because retain only keeps items for which the predicate returns true, and insert only returns true if the item was not previously present in the set.

Since the vector is traversed in order, we end up keeping just the first occurrence of each item.

Fonts:

[remove-duplicates-while-preserving-order-in-rust](https://davidchen.io/blog/remove-duplicates-while-preserving-order-in-rust/)

[how-to-implement-a-trait-for-a-vector-of-generic-type-vect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50381524/how-to-implement-a-trait-for-a-vector-of-generic-type-vect)

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

pub trait Unique<T> {
    fn unique(&mut self);
}

impl<T> Unique<T> for Vec<T>
where
    T: Clone + Eq + std::hash::Hash,
{
    fn unique(self: &mut Vec<T>) {
        let mut seen: HashSet<T> = HashSet::new();
        self.retain(|item| seen.insert(item.clone()));
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut vector = vec![1, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3];
    println!("vector: {:?}", vector);

    vector.unique();
    println!("vector: {:?}", vector);

    assert_eq!(vector, [1, 4, 3, 5, 2]);
}
```

The output:

```
vector: [1, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3]
vector: [1, 4, 3, 5, 2]
```

The [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=36fcbdd03d010b39196d57be36a58f3c).

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to remove duplicates if you don't mind, that the original insertion order gets lost. The resulting array is sorted:

```
let unique = std::collections::BTreeSet::from(arr);
let arr = unique.into_iter().collect::<Vec<_>>();
println!("{arr:?}");
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=3c58c9573645e20ffa9d25db22166f60)